# Setting User's object's password and saving it

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a small project, just to practice and learn Django. I've decided to at first start from creating user authentication in wide meaning of that term. I got stuck on issue with registration. I don't know what I should provide to set_password method as first positional argument, and to save method. Self argument is needed, when I am trying to type there **'request'**, I am getting following error:

> TypeError at /register/ super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Here's register view which I use:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            username = cd['username']
            email = cd['email']
            password1 = cd['password1']
            password2 = cd['password2']
            user = User
            user.username = username
            user.email = email
            if password1 == password2:
                user.set_password(request, password1)
                user.save(request)
                # redirect to success page
            else:
                # return error
        else:
            # return error
```

And here's my form's code:

```
class UserCreateForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

I'd be very appreciate if you will help me to solve this problem, or maybe refer the other way to register user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call the User class to instantiate it.

```
user = User()
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I can overlook that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `create_user` method:

```
   ...
   if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        if cd['password1'] == cd['password2']:
            User.objects.create_user(
                cd['username'],
                cd['email'],
                cd['password1'],
            )
            # Redirect to success page
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much,  you're right it's better method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read some more about python classes.
You don't pass a parameter for self - it's just a notation for python class methods, the self stands for an instance and when calling an instance method you pass all the other parameters skipping self.
I'm not sure if it fixes everything but the mistakes I see in your code are:
- the correct way to instantiate class: user = User() (the way you do it you just get a reference to a class); you can also pass the username and email as parameters when instantiating,
- the correct way to call the user methods is: user.set_password(password) and user.save()

Comment: I agree with you, I have no sufficent knowledge about Pythons' classes. Thanks for your tips.